# Is it possible to get the email addresses of the participants in an Azure Communication Services call?

Tags: azure-communication-services

I am getting the ID (=object ID) of the Teams user who participated in the Teams meeting with util.js in the azure communication services sample app, but is it possible to get the email address (=userPrincipalName)?

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial/blob/main/Project/src/Utils/Utils.js

````
        if (isCommunicationUserIdentifier(identifier)) {
            return identifier.communicationUserId;
        } else if (isPhoneNumberIdentifier(identifier)) {
            return identifier.phoneNumber;
        } else if (isMicrosoftTeamsUserIdentifier(identifier)) {
            return identifier.microsoftTeamsUserId;
        } else if (isUnknownIdentifier(identifier) && identifier.id === '8:echo123'){
            return 'Echo Bot';
        } else {
            return 'Unknown Identifier';
        }```
````

Comment: If it's the same tenant, you can get it with the Graph API based on the ID, but I don't think you can get it if it's a different tenant.

Comment: The Teams meeting attendance report also shows the email addresses of external users.

Answer (score 0):

The email address is not included in the underlying meeting roster and thus is not available via the ACS SDK.

As you indicate, you can get the email/UPN vai Graph API, provided your app has been granted appropriate Graph API consent.